# Inverting op amp gain using high value resistors and using oscilloscope measuremnts

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, noise, oscilloscope, gain

[image: inverting op amp configuration]

I built an inverting op amp circuit as shown in above figure using varying values for Rf and Rin.

When I used Rf=10kohm and Rin=100ohm, my measured gain (using national instrument's virtual oscilloscop) was 98.88 which is very close to the expected gain of 100.

When I used Rf=1Mohm and Rin=10k, my expected gain was 100 but the measured gain using the virtual oscilloscope is only 89.99. In addition, using a real physical oscilloscope (AGILENT DSO-X 2012A), my gain turned to be about 67.1 and was fluctuating a lot.

I read that higher resistor values result in higher noise as I had seen in the measurements but why are the measurements using the physical oscilloscope so much noisier and the gain so much lower than the virtual instrument one? And why is it that for the same expected (calculated) gain, using resistors of high value result in lower gains relative to using resistors of low values? Is it right for me to believe that having more noise should not affect the gain produced but will merely make the readings fluctuate?

Comment: What op amp are you using, and what frequency input? And what power supply?

Comment: Sounds like there is an issue with loading here. If you are using a probe with an internal resistance of 10 MOhm to measure the voltage over a 100 Ohm resistor, there will virtually be no loading effect because the probe would behave similarly to that of an open circuit (100 Ohm << 10 MOhm). But if the resistor you had measured over was around 1 MOhm, now the 10 MOhm probe will load your circuit causing larger unexpected changes in voltage.

Comment: More than that, did you take into account the possibility of parts tolerances?

Comment: Also, what's the magnitude of your input voltage? Is there any distortion? I simulated a bunch of different op amps, and even tried a custom one with terrible parameters and didn't see what you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what amplifier you are using, or what measurement frequency.

In an ideal world, you would get the 100x gains you calculate. So the puzzle is, given your limited information, to guess what is causing the situation to be non-ideal?

If you are measuring with a high AC frequency, then stray capacitance across Rf would reduce its impedance.

If you are measuring with a high AC frequency, and using an amplifier with a limited gain bandwidth product, you might be so far down the gain/frequency curve that the gain has fallen to less than 100x.

If you are measuring at DC, with a poor amplifier, or an old/damaged/wet Rf, then there could be a resistive path shunting Rf, reducing its effective value.

It's possible to do further experiments to see which if any of these are causing the problem. Change the measurement frequency. Measure the amplifier open loop gain. Load the output of the amplifier with different load resistors. Replace the single Rf with a low impedance 10:1 potential divider and a series resistor of 10% of the value (should give the same gain, but with lower feedback impedances).

This sort of investigation is what engineers have to do all the time. Remember, that in an apparent impossibility like this, the measurement, or at least some aspect of it, is always correct. What is at fault is your assumption of what exactly the measurement setup is. 'The measurement setup' of course includes the thing you are measuring, the stimulus, the meter, the connections, and anything that could influence it. Go investigate.